# undefined method `attribute_method_matcher' for "":String first THEN NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I am working on a project via ruby on rails.

I have my model defined as `hkn_int.rb` and point it to `field_database` table

So when I in rails console, and type `HknInt`, it gives me the details about the table, and I type `HknInt.count`, it also gives me the number of items in the table, but that's the only two commands I can do without an error.

If I type `HknInt.first`, it gives me

> undefined method `attribute_method_matcher' for "":String

Then I type it again `HknInt.first`, it gives me another error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass

It is just weird. When I put the code on another server, it works fine.
But all the configs are the same, should make no difference.

Edit:

Model:

```
class HknInt < TemplateEngineModel
    self.table_name = 'field_database'
    self.primary_key = 'id'
end
```

Database Schema:

```
 HknInt(id: integer, section_id: integer, column_code: integer, created_date: datetime, date_performed: datetime, collapsed: boolean)
```

Comment: can you show the schema for field_database table?

Comment: add model code, please, and a full trace of the error.

Comment: Sorry, just updated

Comment: Is it a single-table inheritance?

Comment: @llya yes, sir, it is sing-table